# How to embed Google Compose Mail window in to Google Sheet Form?

Tags: html, gmail, google-sheets

I won't bore everyone reading this post with the entire background story of why I need to do this. However, I am looking to load the Google Compose Mail page in the HTML form loaded inside a Google Sheet I have created.

I know the link for the Compose email is https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=TO&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY

But I don't know if it is possible to have this link loaded as a view in the HTML service Form.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if so, how to do it?

I could always have a button to load the link in a separate tab... but I would like to have this all kept on screen to be more "professional" looking.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an option to add an iframe or free code, but option exists. I recommend inserting a form if you are looking for a way to get data from users.

Its under "Insert", then "Form..."

Good Luck